# strcmp and fscanf with a While Loop through a file

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, strcmp

I'm having trouble with a specific line of code that is giving me the errors of

> error: invalid conversion from `‘int’` to `‘const char*’`
>
> error:   initializing argument 1 of `‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’`

Does anyone happen to know why? This is the line of code in question.

```
while (strcmp(fscanf(fr, "%s", words), "DONE") != 0)
```

Essentially, my code scans through a file (performing certain operations) until it reaches the key word of "DONE" (without the quotes), at which it exits the file. I'm a beginner C programmer so forgive any inaccuracies/inefficiencies in code.

The full code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fr;

struct player {
    char name[50];
    float DOC;

};

struct player players[50];

int main() {
    fr = fopen ("playerinfo.txt", "r");

    if (ftell(fr) == 0) {
        fclose(fr);
        printf("PLAYER FILE IS EMPTY");
        return 0;
    }

    char words[50];

    while (strcmp(fscanf(fr, "%s", words),"DONE") != 0) {
        float pts;
        fscanf(fr, "%f", pts);

        float asts;
        fscanf(fr, "%f", asts);

        float mins;
        fscanf(fr, "%f", mins);

        struct player *aPlayer;
        float theDOC = (pts + asts) / mins;
        strcpy(aPlayer->name, words);
        aPlayer->DOC = theDOC;
    }

    fclose(fr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `fscanf` return?

Comment: Should I do some sort of do while loop then to perform the operation I have in mind?

Comment: Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,

```
  strcmp(fscanf(fr, "%s", words),"DONE")
```

does not do what you think it does. [`fscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) does not return a pointer to the *scanned* string, rather, it returns a count (`int` type). Your compiler warned you. **[Read the man page before you proceed.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)**

This improper usage causes the warning.

That said, you must check for the success of `scanf()` family of functions, otherwise, you have a very high possibility of ending up with using indeterminate values (think of the content of `words`, if scanning fails).

So, you break the operations into two parts.

- use `fgets()` / `fscanf()` to intake the input (newline trimming, if needed). Check for success of the call.
- compare the input buffer with the required string (`strcmp()`).

---

That said, I really don't see much point of the whole loop, as you'll be creating a new local variable `aPlayer` every time you enter the loop. I hope you know what you're doing.

Disregarding above case, a generic flow should look like

```
input = "Not Done";
while ('input' is not "Done")
     scan values;
     check for succss;
     store into variables;
     scan next 'input'
```

Comment: So should my code look something like this: fscanf, then perform check with the while loop, do the operations, then right before the end of the for loop, fscanf again?

Comment: @Freedom basically, yes, but I'll expand my answer a bit, please hang on.

Comment: I'm going to add my aPlayer to an array of struct players in the future, but that's obviously not ready yet haha, appreciate the help Sourav.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your strcmp() function. Indeed, when you do:

```
strcmp(fscanf(fr, "%s", words),"DONE")
```

you compare the return of fscanf (which is an int) to the `const char *` "DONE". This is impossible. You need to compare directly `words` with `"DONE"`.

You should do something like:

```
int test;
test = fscanf(fr, "%s", words);
while ((test != EOF) && (strcmp(words,"DONE") != 0)) {

         float pts;
         fscanf(fr, "%f", pts);

         float asts;
         fscanf(fr, "%f", asts);

         float mins;
         fscanf(fr, "%f", mins);

         struct player *aPlayer;
         float theDOC = (pts + asts) / mins;
         strcpy(aPlayer->name, words);
         aPlayer->DOC = theDOC;

         test = fscanf(fr, "%s", words);
}
```